# How to change class of element based on javascript variable value?

Tags: javascript

I have the following script:

```
<script>
  window.now = some_int_value;
</script>
```

and the following html:

```
<span class="dot"></span>&nbsp;
<span class="dot active"></span>&nbsp;
<span class="dot"></span>&nbsp;
<span class="dot"></span>&nbsp;
```

How should I change the style of the dot in accordance with `window.now` value? So, if it is equal to 1, then first dot should be 'dot active', if equal to 2, then second and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dot")[window.now-1].className += " active";
```

You can do that (for IE9+ and all other major browsers).

Or you can use

```
document.querySelectorAll(".dot")[window.now-1].className += " active";
```

for IE8+, FF3+, and all other major browsers.

or you can combine them

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName);
    document.getElementsByClassName("dot")[window.now-1].className += " active";
else if(document.querySelectorAll)
    document.querySelectorAll(".dot")[window.now-1].className += " active";
```

[Compatibility Documentation](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html)

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not implemented in IE 7 and (I believe the same is true in IE8)

Comment: Hmm, probably I should assign id for each dot?

Comment: @LA_ if you could that would make it a lot more cross browser compatible

Answer (score 1):

You should consider looking into [jQuery](http://jquery.com), which simplifies working with the DOM a lot.

This is all you'd need for your indicator in jQuery:

```
$('span.dot').eq(window.now - 1).addClass('active');
```

No more

- *"Maybe I should assign an ID to each dot"*
- *"getElementByTagName() is not implemented in some more or less obscure browser"*.
- *"This won't work in IE8"*
- …

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var dots = document.querySelectorAll( '.dot' );

[].slice.call( dots ).forEach( function ( dot, i ) {
    dot.className = 'dot' + ( window.now === i + 1 ? ' active' : '' );
});
```

(This doesn't work in IE8.)

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dKDLx/

(The demo shows that even though the 2. dot had the class "active" set, `window.now = 3;` will cause that class to be "moved" to the 3. dot.)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't, by any chance, supposed to be a 4-dot progress bar/throbber? If so, I'd say just use a gif - there's a site that can generate them for you: http://preloaders.net/

Comment: No, it is not progress bar - it will display active page (like on the main iphone screen).